# C++ - OpenSSL secp256k1 ECDSA - Can't verify using exact copy of hash, whether using string literals or different objects

Tags: c++, networking, openssl, ecdsa, secp256k1

I am trying to sign a hash, create a copy of that hash (specifically client/server related), then verify the signature using the copy of the hash. I don't understand how or why when I have two variables, `hash` and `hashCopy`, with the exact same content, that verification can only work on one of the two depending on which one was signed.

The below code shows what I am talking about.

```
int main()
{
    EC_KEY* myecc = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY* pkey_ = NULL;

    myecc = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
    EC_KEY_generate_key(myecc);
    pkey_ = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(pkey_, myecc);
    myecc = EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(pkey_);
    const EC_GROUP* ecgrp = EC_KEY_get0_group(myecc);

    std::string hash = "126420fb81d58bbb7d86c98e1818f4c9d44acf216471e196ed403a608954cf1d";
    std::string hashCopy = hash;

    std::vector<unsigned char> signature;
    unsigned char pchSig[10000];
    unsigned int nSize = 0;

    ECDSA_sign(0, (unsigned char*)&hash, sizeof(hash), pchSig, &nSize, myecc);
    signature.resize(nSize);
    memcpy(&signature[0], pchSig, nSize);

    if (ECDSA_verify(0, (unsigned char*)&hash, sizeof(hash), &signature[0], signature.size(), myecc) == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Original hash variable verify success\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Original hash variable verify fail\n\n";
    }
    if (ECDSA_verify(0, (unsigned char*)&hashCopy, sizeof(hashCopy), &signature[0], signature.size(), myecc) == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Hash copy variable verify success\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Hash copy variable verify fail\n\n";
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Original hash variable verify success

Hash copy variable verify fail
```

Why does verifying using `hashCopy` fail given that it's the exact same? This variable basically represents the variable on the client side, whereas the original `hash` variable represents the variable on the server side.

Also, if I just pass through a string literal `"1264..."` which is the exact same as `hash` that does not work either.

I also tried this using a copy of the `signature` variable, that made no difference as I would expect.

How do I get the verification of both `hash` and `hashCopy` to work without needing to sign both?

Comment: You should not sign/verify with `&hash`, but with `hash.c_str()` and with `hash.length()` as length.

Comment: Perfect. Works exactly as intended now, greatly appreciate the help.